# AngularJS: Why do custom directives default to being attribute-only?

Tags: angularjs

[Egghead.io](http://egghead.io) has a great explanation of directive restrictions in AngularJS. A custom directive can be defined as follows:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("blah", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "blah directive. nothing to see here."
    };
});
```

This creates a what I will call an **attribute directive** (due to `restrict: "A"`) for the purposes of asking this question. This is actually [Angular's default restriction on a custom directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/773), and this directive can be used like:

```
<div blah>
  <!-- content of directive -->
</div>
```

When I want to create a custom directive, however, I normally go for an **element directive**, like:

```
<blah>
  <!-- content of directive -->
</blah>
```

*How is the former **attribute directive** any better than the latter **element directive** and why was it chosen as the default?*

Comment: One more reason could be IE8 support if you write blah  as element then in IE8 it wont work then you to have write create state like document.createElement("blah") but if you define as attributes it works perfectly with IE8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is my opinion, only:**

There are three possible ways to define a directive in the HTML - attributes, elements and classes. Classes are too lax and confusing, and a best practice would be to separate logic from style. Element directives are too strict - you can only have one "element" directive in a DOM element. That makes them *special* right from the start.

An attribute seems to be the best middle ground between these two extremes - it is clear, allows for multiple directives in an element (If you are following Egghead's videos, the superhero example on "directive to directive communication" shows a kind of "directive hierarchy", elements superseding attributes. Also, and this is very important most of the times (I program for intranet apps, so to me it isn't) attributes allow angularJS templates to be valid HTML.

**EDIT - my two cents would be** that it doesn't matter - in any real scenario, it is a bad idea to trust the "default" configuration of something as primary as the restrict option - setting it explicitly makes for clear, no doubt directives (especially working in team projects, but also anytime, really)

Comment: There are actually 4 ways. You can also use html comments to define a directive. I don't know why one would need that though, possibly for internal use.

Comment: Also with the element directives, old versions of IE do not support new elements and it would result in odd behavior. To overcome that one does need to call `document.createElement('my-directive')`

Answer (score 3):

Angular 1.3 changed the default to be 'AE'. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object.

I'm guessing it was changed because it's "restrict", not "include". So, the default for "restrict" should restrict very little.

What does that mean going forward -- if you see a "restrict: 'E'" line, it actually means "This wasn't meant to be used as an attribute", rather than the potential current meaning of "I simply want to use this as an element".

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be:

**An element-based directive would most often represent structural functionality.**

For instance, I use element-based directives for popups, dialogs, tabbed widgets, and reusable widgets in general. I then can add attribute-based directives to them (say, adding an `ng-click` to a `<ui-button>` directive), but the element name (i.e. the directive name) represents the *structural* semantics of what is being built.